# How should I publish React Native Expo App?

Tags: react-native, expo

When I run a command "expo build:android" I get two options like this:
**Checking if there is a build in progress...
? Would you like to upload a keystore or have us generate one for you?
If you don't know what this means, let us handle it! :)
  1) Let Expo handle the process!
  2) I want to upload my own keystore!
  Answer:**

Then I select 1 option i.e.  'Let Expo handle the process!'

But after this I get ' **false
Publishing to channel 'default'...
Building iOS bundle
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.**'
on console.

Now please suggest me what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try , `expo:start` and then `expo build:android` . Hope it helps.